# TSORT array functioning

Tags: c, sorting

Recently I was solving a problem on spoj about sorting I solved it using python but it gave me tle then I came across this code for the same problem ,the code works fine but can anyone explain me the working of it specially the `ar[a]++` and `ar[i]--` part

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int ar[1000001];

int main(){
    int i,j,a;
    scanf("%d",&j);

    for (i=0;i<j;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a);
        ar[a]++;
    }

    for (i=0;i<1000001;i++){
        while(ar[i]>0){
            printf("\n%d",i);
            ar[i]--;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Google for increment/decrement operators in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#Variant_algorithms) (wiki link) . The code example assumes that the values are limited to the range 0 -> 1000000 . ar[a]++ increments a value in the array while ar[i]-- decrements a value in the array.